# Bad class: class java.lang.String in data formatting from API

Tags: android, retrofit

I getting date data from the api in String in this format: 2019-02-01 12:00:00
How to change this to that format: 02-01 12:00? I want to remove year and seconds.

I've used SimpleDateFormat and DateFormat and after start app is crushing and this what I see in logcat: Bad class: class java.lang.String

```
 String date = item.getDtTxt();
 DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-#### hh:mm");
 binding.dateItem.setText(String.valueOf(dt.format(date)));
```

Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.weatherapp2, PID: 8882
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: 2019-02-01 12:00:00
        at java.util.Date.parseError(Date.java:367)
        at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:448)
```

Answer (score 2):

`format()` accepts object of type `Date` and not `String`. You need to parse your string to get `Date` and then use `format()` to set desired date format, like this.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String date = format.format(Date.parse("Your_date"));
```

Comment: Almost fine, but I have this: Parse error: 2019-02-01 12:00:00

Comment: use the format as you have in your string change `dd/MM/yyyy` to `dd-MM-yyyy` as your string uses `-`

Comment: Still same :/ and I have statement about Parse that is deprecated.

Comment: edited answer, your input date format should be used to parse the original string.

Comment: You mean something like this: 
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
 String myFormat = format.format(Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")); ?

Comment: in your_date you need to pass your date string that you are receiving from  item.getDtTxt();